# Servicestack JSV empty string deserialized as null

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

It seems that JSV deserializes an empty string as null.
The following test fails for JSV but passes for JSON.

```
    class Foo
    {
        public string String { get; set; }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestJsvEmptyString
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestJsv()
        {
            Foo orig = new Foo() { String = string.Empty };

            string jsv = orig.ToJsv();
            Foo fromJsv = jsv.FromJsv<Foo>();

            Assert.AreEqual(orig.String, fromJsv.String);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestJson()
        {
            Foo orig = new Foo() { String = string.Empty };

            string json = orig.ToJson();
            Foo fromJson = json.FromJson<Foo>();

            Assert.AreEqual(orig.String, fromJson.String);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for a great package!

Ron

Answer (score 1):

Empty strings are treated as `null` in the [JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#typeserializer-details-jsv-format), as it has no wire representation.

Comment: The problem is that Servicestack OrmLite serializes objects as JSV, and when read from database we encounter this problem.

Comment: @user3009388 Just don't distinguish between empty string and nulls, otherwise you'd have to avoid using JSV and not blob complex types in OrmLite.